# Rails: Polymorphic association needed for subclasses in STI structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, sti

I'm working on a hobby project and have an abstract `Event` model with STI subclasses `Meal`, `Outing`, `Medication`, etc. The `Event` parent model has `start_time`, `end_time`, `description`, etc.

I want to have nested resources for the various subclasses. For example, I want to be able to attach multiple instances of the `Image` class to any `Event` subclass. I want to be able to attach multiple instances of the `Medicine` class to the `Medication` entities, multiple instance of `Location` to `Outing`, etc.

My reason for considering polymorphism is to provide flexibility so that, conceivably, any of the different types of nested resources could be attached to any of the subclasses of `Event.` This would allow somebody to attach a medicine of "Vitamin D Supplement" to a `Meal`, for example.

My questions are:

1. Should the nested resources be polymorphic?
2. If I make them polymorphic, will all of the instances contain `Event` in the type table?
3. If so, should I just make them `has_many` relationships?
4. Is there any performance advantage to making them `has_many` vs. polymorphic?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes.

(2) Yes, depending on how you handle the polymorphism. Rails allows for STI (single table inheritance) so all subtypes of event can inherit the has_many relation. The related has_many record can have many subtypes, and all of these will appear as relations when called.

(3) has_many can be used in conjunction to polymorphic, they are not mutually exclusive.

(4) Again, the two are not mutually exclusive. In fact, polymorphic is needed on your belongs_to relation. Your related record should include a relation_id and relation_type in its table. If you are using STI, for instance, you would do it like this:

```
class BaseClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo
end

class SubClass < BaseClass
  # inherits has_many :foo relation from BaseClass
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :base_class, polymorphic: true
end

class Bar < Foo
  # inherits belongs_to :base_class from Foo
end
```

When calling sub_class-instance.foos, you should get an ActiveRecord relation of all foos, including subtypes.